# PHP MYSQL PDO - function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got what seems like a zillionth question about the mysql & PDO. I've given myself a task on how to start using PDO instead of the old mysql* PHP functions.

It's little difficult to explain but I'm after making the site as efficient as possible (from the PHP perspective anyway). I've found bunch of good tutorials about the MySQL PDO but I haven't succeeded in finding a solution to this.

Let's assume I want to regularly query various tables for all data they contain; for that purpose I intend to set up a function with one argument - name of the table to query: Something like this:

```
function getData($table)
{
    global $db;
    $SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    $statement = $db->query($SQL_query);
    $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    return $result;
}
```

This works fine; however the function returns only the first 'row' of the table. Now the question is; how do I make the function to return all rows? Can I try something like this:

```
function getData($table)
{
    global $db;
    $SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
            $statement = $db->query($SQL_query);
            while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)
    {
    return $result;
            }
}
```

I would be grateful for any hints / recommendations etc... If there are any best practices for this kind of desired behaviour?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Alternately, you can use [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) and iterate over the result set returned by that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea for this function is quite wrong.

As Mike Brant said, there is no point in selecting all the data from table - you are probably confusing a database with a flat file. You have the power of SQL at your fingertips and it would be a crime not to use it!

So, make your function accept *SQL query* and parameters for it, to be bound as it is required by PDO.

```
function getData()
{
    $global $db;
    $params = func_get_args();
    $query = array_shift($args);

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

and now you can use it like this

```
$rows = getData("SELECT * FROM t WHERE cat=?",$category);
```

neat, eh?

this would be really useful and handy function.

Comment: If I'm reading your code right you actually suggest to not use the query inside the function itself but rather pass it to the function as an argument. Regarding the fetching the whole table I do agree it may not be very elegant. Thanks for your post!

Comment: Yes, exactly. Passing query as a function argument will make it flexible - you'll be able to use any query you need with this  single function

Comment: Right...I intended something slightly different (having one query for each query type distinguished only by table) but this is actually even more flexible. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you probably DO NOT WANT to return all rows of a table. You would probably be better served returning the statement handle to the caller for iteration. Otherwise you are going to load an entire table into memory when you might not actually have the need to do that in your program. This might not be a problem if all your tables do not hold that much data, but would certainly be a memory hog as soon as you start doing this on larger tables.

For example if you are going to simply output the entire table data to a browser client, and let's say you you have a table that have 1000 rows each averaging 1kB of data.  You would have to read 1MB of data into memory if you use you approach vs. only having to hold an average of 1 kB in memory if you let the caller iterate through the result set.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit on the 'returning statement handle to the caller'? Did you mean (similar to 'your common sense') to pass the query to the function as an argument? Thanks!

Comment: @TomasH No, I think @YourCommonSense had a very good suggestion about making your function more flexible with regard to allowing for  different sort of queries and parameters to be sent to the function.  I am suggesting however that it might not always be a good idea to load the entire result set into memory via `fetchAll()` or iterating through the entire result set and then returning a potentially large array of data.  I am suggesting you return the PDOStatement object to the code calling the function such that that code can decide how it will process the result set.

Comment: OK that's also very interesting. I'll have a think if I can conjure something :)